# Parsing CSV based on Popup Properties

Tags: javascript, csv, highcharts, popup, leaflet

I am creating a map using leaflet to show stream temperatures at different locations. I currently have a Highchart line chart created in every popup, however, I can't seem to find a way to make the data in the chart specific to the popup. The data in the map is in geoJSON with a SiteID, x coordinate, and y coordinate. The popup currently binds the feature.properties.Site. The data feeding the chart is in CSV to allow for easy updating and is organised like:

date, siteA, siteB 
nov-1-2016, 6, 8 
nov-2-2016, 7 9

Do I need to re-parse the data every time the popup is open to only parse the relevant site or is there an option in Highcharts that would allow me to parse all of the data but only plot the relevant site?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your data format cannot be used with Highchart's data module, which can load CSV. The problem is that your date is not in number type, so you have to parse it with Date.parse function.

There are two ways to parse your data, you can get your CSV and transform it to desired CSV, that can be read by Highchart's data module. Another option would be to parse your data and update your series with series.update.

You can also modify your data before it is applied to chart by using:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.parsed

Live example of parsing CSV and using data module:
https://jsfiddle.net/45khuo3h/

```
// Your input csv file
var csv = 'date, siteA, siteB' + '\n' +
  'nov-1-2016, 6, 8' + '\n' +
  'nov-2-2016, 7, 9';

// Modify your csv
var modifyCSV = function(csv) {
  return csv.split('\n')
    .map(line => line.split(',')
      .map(el => {
        if (el.split('-').length === 3) {
          el = Date.parse(el);
        }
        return el;
      })
      .reduce((a, b) => a + ',' + b)
    )
    .reduce((a, b) => a + '\n' + b, '');
}

// Options
var options = {
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
  },
  data: {
    csv: modifyCSV(csv),
    parsed: function() {
      console.log(this);
      // Modify your data here
      this.columns[0][2] += 100000000;
    }
  }
}

// Render chart
var chart = Highcharts.chart(options);
```